# Getting error in Access database connection

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to connect to my database and I'm getting this error message (ex):
[image]

I've another function which opens DB and load some data, it works fine without any error... But when I try to use this, it returns me this error, the **line 175 is "cn.Open()".**

My **connection string** and **Local_DB** is both same as other functions which are working without errors.

```
Private Sub AtualizaClientes(ID As Integer)
        ' Local da DataBase
        Dim Local_DB As String
        Local_DB = "C:\Users\Heitor BASAM\Desktop\Sistema\DataBase_Sistema.accdb"

Try
            Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
            cn.ConnectionString = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={Local_DB}"
            cn.Open()

            cn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.ToString)

        End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Is your database file password protected?

Comment: No! I checked it...

Answer (score 1):

Glad you fixes your problem! Just a few bits to tidy up the code.

Always use `Using...End Using` with database objects that expose a `Dispose` method. They may be using unmanaged objects and their dispose methods must run to release these resources. The `End Using` takes care of this for you even if there is an error.

You can let the error bubble up to the calling code, user interface code. Wrap the call to AtualizaClientes in a `Try...Catch...End Try`

```
Private Sub AtualizaClientes(ID As Integer)
    Dim Local_DB = "C:\Users\Heitor BASAM\Desktop\Sistema\DataBase_Sistema.accdb"
    Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection($"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={Local_DB}")
        cn.Open()
    End Using
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

You would add the `Try...End Try` to the UI code. Example...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim id As Integer = 7
    Try
        AtualizaClientes(id)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this tip! But after `End Using`I should add "`Try...Catch...End`"?

Comment: Got it !!! And between `Using...End Using` I insert `cn.Open()`, MySql Insertions and etc, right?

Comment: Yes. The code that uses the connection would go there. Don't open the connection until the line before the execute. You can nest Using blocks for other database objects that have a dispose method.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem! I've a function when a especify textbox is changed, it calls this "AtualizaClientes" function. The problem is, when you load the form, it runs a "TextChanged" event in every textbox and trys to run the database before loading it. This was causing the error message.

To solve this problem, I made a boolean variable which returns true after loading the database. So, I changed my textchanged event to run only if this variable is true.